# Second Opinion Needed on Code Snippet

Tags: vb.net

In the code below, I asked the writer of this code if it was correct. He told me it was correct. I have a problem with the code below the comment indicated by   Not sure why this check is done. AFAIK the check always evaluates to true. Do I stand to be corrected ? I would like to take this to my manager as there are no other technical people in the company I can ask. Opinions appreciated.

To clarify isn't Index.SubItems the same as Items(index) ?

```
For each lii as ListViewItem in ListView1.Items

'<?> Not sure why this check is done 
                    If lii.SubItems(ReconGrid.ref).Text = ListView1.Items(lii.Index).SubItems(ReconGrid.ref).Text Then
                        ListView1.Items(li.Index).SubItems(ReconGrid.obal).Text = lii.SubItems(ReconGrid.cbal).Text
                        ListView1.Items(li.Index).SubItems(ReconGrid.lstObal).Text = lii.SubItems(ReconGrid.rbr).Text
                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: Without more information I don't think anyone is going to be able to tell you if this is good or bad code

Comment: The programmer has stored data as a list of arrays for a listview control from vb forms. In the one loop he references these rows from the listview control using lii. Is lii.items referring to the same row as items(lii.index)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out I was right. I was silly. I implemented a test case and proved that the condition in the if statement is always true. So much for that !